# AppDynamic casue java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, obfuscation, appdynamics

when I was working on android studio and enable the code obfuscation for the app
[image: enable the code obfuscation in build.gradle file]

it returns error said :app:appDynamicProcessProguardMappingRelease cannot get property 'buildID on extra extention as it does not exist[image]

after checking the community solutions from AppDynamics from here
https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/21.x/latest/en/end-user-monitoring/mobile-real-user-monitoring/instrument-android-applications/customize-the-android-build/configure-proguard-to-prevent-obfuscation-and-class-removal
I added it in the proguard-rules.pro file
after that, the build is fine and launched successed
but app crashed with below error[image: error message from logcat]

Does anyone have some idea?
Thanks so much

Expecting app do not crash

Comment: looks like it's missing some value of buildId as mentioned in this thread:
https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/End-User-Monitoring-EUM/Android-plugin-21-5-0-issue-with-missing-quot-buildID-quot/td-p/44210

try to use the latest version of appdynamics if that include this fix

Comment: Hi Rax, thanks for your reply. this issue should be from the ProGuard, the account name and licenseKey was added into the build. it would work when the ProGuard was disabled, but I want to find a way to keep proGuard's code obfuscation and make the appDynamics work.

Answer (score 0):

For correct working AppDynamics requires exceptions to obfuscation.

Update *proguard-rules.pro* with:

```
-keep class com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.DontObfuscate
-keep @com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.DontObfuscate class * { *; }
```

Reference: https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/23.x/latest/en/end-user-monitoring/mobile-real-user-monitoring/instrument-android-applications/customize-the-android-build/configure-proguard-to-prevent-obfuscation-and-class-removal

Comment: Hi Ingmar, I have added this, but not working